# Which package provides the "make" executable?

Tags: nixos

I've tried https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#make but it returns around 314 results spread across 20 pages so not very convenient.

I've also tried the `stdenv` package with no change in behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the following:

```
$ readlink $(which make)
/nix/store/qwl4psnv7qnbs69qhd5w2jfcp7a686vw-gnumake-4.2.90pre2491_48c8a11/bin/make
```

So the name of the package is `gnumake`. Package search [reveals](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#gnumake) five packages of which four are GNU make.

`nix repl` on my NixOS 18.03 system shows:

```
$ nix repl
[...]
nix-repl> (import <nixpkgs> {}).gnumake
«derivation /nix/store/b1imiipjihl8k9n48smbvjpsjcjq0qfj-gnumake-4.2.1.drv»
```

With GitHub's search you can [figure out](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/search?q=%22name+%3D+gnumake%22&unscoped_q=%22name+%3D+gnumake%22) where derivations named `gnumake` are defined, which is in `pkgs/development/tools/build-managers/gnumake`